# How to solve this very hard nonlinear ordinary differential equation: $4y^{3}+7x\sin(x)+4x^{4}-(16\cos(y)-7x-\frac{7}{4}y^{2})y'=-e^{y-x}+\sinh(y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving

**$4\cdot y^{3}+7\cdot x\cdot\sin(x)+4\cdot x^{4}-\left(16\cdot\cos(y)-7\cdot x-\frac{7}{4}\cdot y^{2}\right)\cdot y'=-e^{y-x}+\sinh(y)$**

I tried a lot to solve this
differential equation.
I think it must have a strange integrator factor.

Comment: 1. Please write formulas in MathJax.
$$$$
2. Please show us your attempts to solve this task so that we can really help you.

Comment: Since you tried "a lot", please include your attempts to solve this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: May I ask what is the origin of this rather bizarre equation?

Comment: This nonlinear first order differential equation was a score question of Amir Kabir University of Iran. There were 7 questions and I solved 6 of them. This question is not complete. I think it can be solved by finding an integrator

Comment: This differential equation Mx is not equal to Ny, so it is not complete and needs an integrator! Because it cannot be converted to any of the known first-order equations such as diffusible, Bernoulli, homogeneous, Chloro, Lagrange... I think the only hope is to find the integral factor of the structure

Comment: Thank you. Now, just edit the two comments above into your post using the "Edit" button. Finally, [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/) is a website which searches Stack Exchange for mathematical formulas : so search for your equation here and see if you find any useful hits.

Comment: What's the name of this equation?

Comment: I think it must have a strange and very good integrator for the equation to be complete and solved! Because it is not homogeneous and Bernoulli and...